# Displaying the statistics from emp and dept table in a single query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two table emp and dept

Emp table has following fields:

```
EMPNO   ENAME   JOB MGR HIREDATE    SAL COMM    DEPTNO
```

Dept table has following fields:

```
DEPTNO  DNAME   LOC
```

Rules are:-
a. total employees in each department
b. highest salary of each department
c. least salary of each department.
d. No. of emps with highest salary in each department. 
e. No. of emps with least salary in each department.
f. employee name/id with highest salary in each department.
g. employee name/id with least salary in each department.
h. Names of all employees belonging to eachdepartment.

o/p is as follows:
[image]

for data of emp and dept table refer this link

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1bc2b8

Thanks in advance..

Comment: This more like a job spec I would expect to see posted on a freelancer site. What are you hoping for in an SO answer?

Comment: Based on this example will try toapply it my data...

Comment: You did a great job giving us the information in an accessible way, but you did not show us what you tried in order to achieve the results you are after.

Comment: Splited up the queries into parts...
1)
```
SELECT d.deptno, COUNT(e.ename) as TOT_EMPS,
        MAX(e.sal) as ABC,MIN(e.sal)
FROM dept d 
INNER JOIN emp e 
ON d.deptno=e.deptno  
GROUP BY d.deptno 
```
2)
```
select  emp.sal as ABC1,count(emp.sal)
from emp
inner join dept on emp.deptno = dept.deptno
inner join
(
select emp.deptno, max(emp.sal) sal
from emp
group by emp.deptno
) ss on emp.deptno = ss.deptno and emp.sal = ss.sal
group by emp.sal
```
but not able to join those queries..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `analytical function` and `GROUP BY` as follows:

```
SELECT D.deptno,
       COUNT(1) TOTAL_EMPS,
       MAX(sal) AS MAX_SAL,
       MIN(sal) AS MIN_SAL,
       SUM(CASE WHEN SAL = MINSAL THEN 1 END) EMP_MIN_SAL,
       SUM(CASE WHEN SAL = MAXSAL THEN 1 END) EMP_MAX_SAL,
       MAX(CASE WHEN RNMIN = 1 THEN E.empno END) EMP_WITH_MIN_sAL,
       MAX(CASE WHEN RNMAX = 1 THEN E.empno END) EMP_WITH_MAX_sAL,
       LISTAGG(E.ename, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY E.EMPNO) ALL_EMPS
  FROM dept D JOIN (SELECT T.*, 
                           MIN(SAL) OVER (PARTITION BY deptno) MINSAL, 
                           MAX(SAL) OVER (PARTITION BY deptno) MAXSAL, 
                           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY deptno ORDER BY SAL) RNMIN,
                           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY deptno ORDER BY SAL DESC) RNMAX 
                      FROM emp T) E
    ON E.deptno = D.deptno
GROUP BY D.deptno;
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1bc2b8/214)

Answer (score 0):

Using `aggregate functions` and `group by`....without using any `analytical functions`

```
Select deptno,
    COUNT(*) tot_emps,
    MAX(sal) max_sal,
    MIN(sal) min_sal,
    COUNT(sal) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY sal desc) emp_max_salary,
    COUNT(sal) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY sal asc) emp_min_salary,
    MAX(empno || '-' || ename)  KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY sal DESC) emp_with_max_salary,
    MIN(empno || '-' || ename)  KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY sal ASC)emp_with_min_salary,
    LISTAGG(ename,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ename) emp_list
FROM emp
    GROUP BY deptno
    ORDER BY deptno;
```

[SQLFiddle_Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1bc2b8/218)